# c++ function polymorphism/template

Tags: c++, c++11

My goal is to provide three ways calling the function `listen()`. Is there a better way to do this? (Like using template or default value parameters so I can implement only one `listen()` function) 
**My current approach**

```cpp
void listen(const int &port,
                 const std::function<void(std::string err)> &f) {
    http_server_.listen(port, [f](std::string err) { f(err); });
}
void listen(const int &port, const std::function<void()> &f) {
    http_server_.listen(port, [f](std::string err) { f(); });
}
void listen(const int &port) {
    http_server_.listen(port, [](std::string err) {});
}
```

I have tried the template approach which looks like

```cpp
template <typename Func> void listen(const int &port, Func f = {}) {
    // do some if-else here.
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your current approach looks good to me, except that `port` and `f` should be passed by value, `err` should be passed by const ref (**both** in the template parameter of `std::function` and in the lambdas), and (if you had at least C++14) `f` should be captured using `f = std::move(f)` instead of just `f`.

Comment: Are you limited to C++11? `if constexpr` from C++17 could potentially be useful here, but in C++11 your solution is as short as it gets.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you provide a simple example? I am thinking of rewriting my code with c++17 since there are much more new features.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why caturing f with std::move() is better?

Comment: Because that would move it instead of copying? Remember that it can be an arbitrary lambda/functor with a bunch of state (i.e. member variables).

Comment: I agree with HolyBlackCat; it looks good for now. Adding template metaprogramming here would only obfuscate things and slow down compilation.

Comment: You don't need to "rewrite in C++17". In theory you should be able to just flip a compiler switch and gain access to new shiny features.

Comment: "better" is asking for an opinion.  Provide a problem or an objective criteria.  "like" clause is close, but still vague?  I think you ade asking for a more DRY solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO your approach is close to optimal. If I was writing this, I'd make only minor changes:

```
void listen(int port, std::function<void(const std::string &err)> f)
{
    http_server_.listen(port, std::move(f));
}
void listen(int port, std::function<void()> f)
{
    http_server_.listen(port, [f = std::move(f)](const std::string &){f();});
}
void listen(int port)
{
    // Are you sure the lambda is needed? Maybe passing `nullptr` will work.
    http_server_.listen(port, [](const std::string &){});
}
```

Here, `f = std::move(f)` (instead of `f`) in lambda capture requires at least C++14. If you're limited to C++11 and can't do it, then you should change `f` back to be passed by a const reference (in the second overload).

---

Combining those into a single function can't be done easily before C++17, and would require more boilerplate than it's going to eliminate.

In C++17 you can use `if constexpr`, but if you ask me, it still only makes things worse:

```
template <typename, typename...> struct always_false : std::false_type {};

template <typename F = std::nullptr_t>
void listen(int port, F &&f = nullptr)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_nullptr_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<F>>>)
    {
        http_server_.listen(port, [](const std::string &) {});
    }
    else
    {
        http_server_.listen(port, [f = std::forward<F>(f)](const std::string &err)
        {
            if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<const F &, const std::string &>)
                std::invoke(f, err);
            else if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<const F &>)
                std::invoke(f);
            else
                static_assert(always_false<F>, "The function is invalid.");
        });
    }
}
```

Not only this requires twice as much typing, it also prevents the caller from using SFINAE to inspect which function parameters your function does or doesn't accept.

Comment: And if you go to C++20 you can have the first version without the overhead of `std::function` https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5q15s6PT1

Answer (score 0):

```
void listen(int port, std::function<void(std::string err)> f) {
  http_server_.listen(port, std::move(f));
}
void listen(int port, std::function<void()> f={}) {
  listen(port, [f=std::move(f)](std::string err) { f(); });
}
```

this is more DRY.  In [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20) you can save a bit of overhead:

```
void listen(int port, std::invocable<std::string> auto f) {
  http_server_.listen(port, std::move(f));
}
void listen(int port, std::invocable<> auto f=[]{}) {
  listen(port, [f=std::move(f)](std::string const&) { f(); });
}
```

using concepts, but I would not bother.